# How can I add a new documents template in Shopware?

Tags: smarty, shopware

I have created a new template, that extends the **Bare** template of **Shopware 5.3.7** though the backend, then I activated it.

I added the file `index_mydocument.tpl`  inside the `documents/` directory and added a new entry **MyDocument** in *Basic Settings > PDF document creation*. The template path of that entry is `index_mydocument.tpl`.

[image: Picture of the configuration]

The I deleted all caches, reloaded the backend and tried generating a "Preview" in "Basic Settings > PDF document creation > MyDocument"

[image: Picture of the preview button]

It returns the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SmartyException: Unable to load template snippet
>   'documents/index_mydocument.tpl' in
>   /project/shopware/engine/Library/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php
>   on line 127

What can I do so that Shopware notices my new **index_mydocument.tpl**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The shop configuration under

*Basic Settings > Shop settings > Shops > My Shop > Document template*

was still set to the Bare template.

[image: wrong setting]

I changed it to:

[image: correct setting]

and now the PDF generation works.